Updatable views with INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers or constraints?
We have a number of tables we rotate through for weekly processes, and we want to keep up to 10 weeks around for review.
Currently we have 10 tables with the same structure (weeks 0-9) and a view with an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger.  The view has a structure like the one below.
I was wondering whether INSERTS would perform better if I dropped the INSTEAD OF trigger and replaced it with a week column and constraints on the value of that column?
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwWeeklyProcess]
AS
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week0
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week1
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week2
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week3
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week4
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week5
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week6
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week7
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week8
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Process_week9
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[InsteadTrigger] on [dbo].[vwWeeklyProcess]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @wk int = datepart(ww,GETDATE()) % 10;
  IF (@wk = 0)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week0
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
  ELSE IF (@wk = 1)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week1
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
  ELSE IF (@wk = 2)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week2
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
  ELSE IF (@wk = 3)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week3
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
  ELSE IF (@wk = 4)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week4
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
  ELSE IF (@wk = 5)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week5
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
  ELSE IF (@wk = 6)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week6
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
  ELSE IF (@wk = 7)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week7
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
  ELSE IF (@wk = 8)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week8
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
  ELSE IF (@wk = 9)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Process_week9
       SELECT *
       FROM inserted
END;
GO


It's just not straightforward to set up a test bed with the same data volumes.  I was wondering if there was anyone out there who had some "best practice" experience with this sort of thing

To generate sufficient load for testing, you may want to consider a tool like SQL Query Stress. That would allow you to test any arrangement you'd like under an appropriate level of concurrency to your workload.

I agree with the others that you should test your solution using one of the linked references.  However, in my experience the way you have it currently setup will probably result in the lowest number of logical reads per insert operation.  It's been a long time since I've done partitioned views but I know that they perform rather poorly on the insert side most of the time.
I whipped up a quickie test (only three rows of insert!) with two tables and the difference was pretty profound.  The IF/ELSE branch method only took 11 logical reads.  While the constraint method took 21 to do the same insert.  Fuzzy memory says that the constraint method has all of the inserts attempting to go to each table, but the constraint keeps it out.  Kind of like an insert knocking on all 10 doors.  While the if/else branch method targets a specific table.
I used https://statisticsparser.com/# to parse the statistics io output and get a total.
Anyways.
Scenario One - If/Else
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.vwTest 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Test001 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Test002

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test001
    (
    TestID INT NOT NULL
    , TestValue NVARCHAR(50) NULL
    )

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test002
    (
    TestID INT NOT NULL
    , TestValue NVARCHAR(50) NULL
    )

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vwTest AS
    (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Test001
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Test002
    )

GO

CREATE TRIGGER trgvwTest ON dbo.vwTest 
    INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @wk INT = DATEPART(WEEK, SYSUTCDATETIME()) % 2

    IF @wk = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Test001 
        SELECT * FROM INSERTED AS I
    END
    ELSE IF @wk = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Test002 
        SELECT * FROM INSERTED AS I
    END

END

GO

SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON 
INSERT INTO dbo.vwTest 
(TestID, TestValue)
VALUES (1, '1')
    , (2, '2')
    , (3, '3')

Scenario 2 - Constraints
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.vwTestconst
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Test003
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Test004


CREATE TABLE dbo.Test003
    (
    TestID INT NOT NULL
    , TestValue NVARCHAR(50) NULL
    , WeekID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT chk004week0 CHECK (WeekID = 0)
    , PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (TestID, WeekID)
    )

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test004
    (
    TestID INT NOT NULL
    , TestValue NVARCHAR(50) NULL
    , WeekID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT chk004week1 CHECK (WeekID = 1)
    , PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (TestID, WeekID)
    )

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vwTestconst AS
    (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Test003
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Test004
    )

GO

SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON 

INSERT INTO dbo.vwTestconst 
(TestID, TestValue, WeekID )
VALUES (1, '1', DATEPART(WEEK, SYSUTCDATETIME()) % 2)
    , (2, '2', DATEPART(WEEK, SYSUTCDATETIME()) % 2)
    , (3, '3', DATEPART(WEEK, SYSUTCDATETIME()) % 2)


Thanks for doing the test.  The "fuzzy memory" stuff about how the constraints work was the kind of group knowledge I was looking for.
